# Using Add Field, Calculate Field within ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, spatial-join, statistics

I have two questions regarding ModelBuilder.

1. I have a point layer with Crop Yield values. I need to Add Field called "Count", then do a Calculate Field, Count = 1. The problem that I'm running into is that in Model builder, when I try to insert a Calculate Field tool, "Count" field does not exist yet so I cannot reference that. How do I get the Count field to appear in MB before running the Calculate Field operation?
2. I need to do a Spatial Join in ModelBuilder as well. I have done a Multiple Buffer operation with 7 concentric circles, and I need to join each field (each "doughnut) in that layer with the points that fall within it. I then need to perform several operations including Sum, Min, Max, Std Dev. When I manually do a "right-click" Spatial Join (right click the layer itself and select Join), this is no problem. Here's the dialog I would like to see in Model builder:

[image]

However, the Spatial Join tool that is brought into ModelBuilder is significantly different. In it, you have the list of fields from the Join Feature, and you have to select an individual operation for each one.

[image]

Can someone tell me how to do this Join in ModelBuilder?

Comment: Calculate Geometry function is used to calculate feature geometry (eg. area, x/y values...etc).  Do you mean calculate field instead?

Comment: My mistake - yes that should be Calculate Field, not Geometry.

Comment: As you will see in the [Tour] there should be only one question per question.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the [merge rules](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00210000000s000000). By right clicking on the fields you want to analysis and going "Merge Rule", you'll be presented with the options for the merge. These options include First, Last, Join, Sum, Mean, Median, Mode, Min, Max, Standard Deviation and Count - Refer to the heading Merge rule in the link provided for more information. Also see example below

[image]

Additionally, there is [information here](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005s0000002p000000) which talks about "summarizing the data in your table" before joining the table that may assist further.

Answer (score 0):

For your first question, make sure the add field object is created and connected to the feature class before the calculate field object.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance - this first question kind of resolved itself. It was acting quirky and finally, after multiple attempts, showed my Count field in the subsequent operation.

However, I am still stumped by the second question. Anyone know how I can perform these summary operations in ModelBuilder?

Thanks